# Code isn't working for a list in the post method?

Tags: apexrest, rest-service, apex-webservice

What are the changes to be performed to send the list of json's, currently its working only for 1 account record. looking for the list of json as a body to pass it to salesforce.

Code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/abc/*')
global without sharing class abc
{
 @HttpPost
  global static String doUpsert()
  {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        //system.debug('-----------data--------'+req) ;
        system.debug('-----------data--------'+req.requestBody.toString()) ;

    list<master> b = (list<master>)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),list<master>.class);

        system.debug('----------b----------'+b);

    list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();
    RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'];
        Account acc = new Account();

        if(!b.isEmpty())
        {

            for(master mas: b)
            { 

                    acc.Magento_ID__c = string.valueof(mas.MagentoID);               
                    acc.firstname= string.valueof(mas.fname);                
                    acc.lastname= string.valueof(mas.lname);               
                    acc.Phone= string.valueof(mas.Phon);

                if(!string.isBlank(mas.DateCustomerAdded))   
                {
                    acc.Date_Customer_Added__c = date.valueof(mas.DateCustomerAdded);
                }
                    acc.Email__c= string.valueof(mas.Email);                
                    acc.Billing_Street_1__c = string.valueof(mas.BillingStreet);                
                    acc.Billing_City__c = string.valueof(mas.BillingCity);                
                    acc.Billing_State_Province__c = string.valueof(mas.BillingStateProvince);                
                    acc.Billing_Country__c = string.valueof(mas.BillingCountry);                
                    acc.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c = string.valueof(mas.BillingZip);               
                    acc.Shipping_Street_1__c = string.valueof(mas.ShippingStreet);                
                    acc.Shipping_City__c = string.valueof(mas.ShippingCity);                
                    acc.Shipping_State_Province__c = string.valueof(mas.ShippingStateProvince);                
                    acc.Shipping_Country__c = string.valueof(mas.ShippingCountry);                
                    acc.Shipping_Zip_Postal_Code__c = string.valueof(mas.ShippingZip);               
                    acc.Hair_Type__c = string.valueof(mas.HairType);                
                    acc.Hair_Color__c = string.valueof(mas.HairColor);

                if(!string.isBlank(mas.PersonDOB))   
                {
                    acc.PersonBirthdate = date.valueof(mas.PersonDOB);
                }
                    acc.Hair_Texture__c = string.valueof(mas.HairTexture);                
                    acc.Hair_Porosity__c = string.valueof(mas.HairPorosity);                
                    acc.Hair_Length__c = string.valueof(mas.HairLength);                
                    acc.Person_Using_Product__c = string.valueof(mas.PersonUsProduct);
                   acc.Hair_Goals__c = string.valueof(mas.HairGoals);                
                    acc.Skin_Issue__c = string.valueof(mas.SkinIssue);

                if(!string.isBlank(mas.OptInEmail))   
                {
                    acc.Opt_In_to_Email__c = Boolean.valueof(mas.OptInEmail);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.OptInWeeklyDeals))   
                {
                    acc.Opt_In_to_Weekly_Deals__c = Boolean.valueof(mas.OptInWeeklyDeals);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.OptInPromos))   
                {
                    acc.Opt_In_to_Promos__c = Boolean.valueof(mas.OptInPromos);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.OptInNews))   
                {
                    acc.Opt_In_to_News__c = Boolean.valueof(mas.OptInNews);
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(mas.OptInCommunity))   
                {
                    acc.Opt_In_to_Community_Commerce__c = Boolean.valueof(mas.OptInCommunity);
                }

                    acc.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordType.id;

                accList.add(acc);
            }   
                List<Database.UpsertResult> upsertResult = Database.upsert(accList,Account.Fields.Email__c,false);
                //Insert accList;
                system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+upsertResult);
        }

        // return JSON.serialize(acc); 
        return 'Success';
  }

   global class master
   {
       public string MagentoID;
       public string fname;
       public string lname;
       public string Phon;
       public string Email; 
       public string DateCustomerAdded;
       public string BillingStreet;
       public string BillingCity;
       public string BillingStateProvince;
       public string BillingCountry;
       public string BillingZip;
       public string ShippingStreet;
       public string ShippingCity;
       public string ShippingStateProvince;
       public string ShippingCountry;
       public string ShippingZip;
       public string HairType;
       public string HairColor;
       public string PersonDOB;
       public string HairTexture;
       public string HairPorosity;
       public string HairLength;
       public string PersonUsProduct;
       public string HairGoals;
       public string SkinIssue;
       public string OptInEmail;
       public string OptInWeeklyDeals;
       public string OptInPromos;
       public string OptInNews;
       public string OptInCommunity;      
       public master()
       {

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: If you select your code and hit `CTRL + K`, it will indent for you.

Comment: i have tried  : Transient List<Database.UpsertResult> upsertResult;                                                 upsertResult = Database.upsert(accList,Account.Fields.Email__c,false);     But still no luck. Looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop logic change would be:

```
list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();
for(master mas: b)
{
    Account acc = new Account();
    accList.add(acc);

    acc.Magento_ID__c = ...
    ...
}
return JSON.serialize(accList);
```

Note that setting the JSON in the `RestResponse` body rather than returning it avoids unwanted escaping.